# Turn a rotated QRect into a QPolygon

Tags: qt, collision-detection, qpolygon, qrect

I am trying to check collisions between a QPolygon and a QRect by turning the QRect into a QPolygon. However, the rectangle might also have a rotation that I have added, so I am wondering how I would turn that QRect into a QPolygon taking into account the rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can convert `QRect` into `QPolygon` using `QMatrix::mapToPolygon`.

Here is the description: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix.html#mapToPolygon

I believe you will be able to convert your `QRect` into `QPolygon` taking the rotation matrix into account.

Edit: Actually `QTransform::mapToPolygon` can be more suitable in this case. Please try:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#mapToPolygon

as well.